# Get new master changes into your branch

Tags: git, github

I created a new branch from `master` in which I have been working for the past few days. 
Now `master` has some new changes that will help my branch pass some failing test, therefore my question is:

How can I get these new changes from `master` to my branch so I can then submit my PR to GitHub and make the test pass?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can `git pull` to bring in these new changes from the remote `master`.  So, use either:

```
git pull origin master           # merge strategy
git pull --rebase origin master  # rebase strategy
```

You may get merge conflicts from either type of pull, which you would then have to resolve.  There is an edge case here, which is that perhaps your working directory and/or stage are not clean at the moment.  In this case, you may do one of the three following options:

- Do a `git commit` to commit your work
- Do a `git stash` to temporarily shelve your work, then reapply the stash later
- You could do a `git reset` and discard your working directory or stage